# How did this orderly get beat up?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-2-judgment-day

After the alarm is sounded during Sarah Connor's attempted escape from the hospital, there is a scene which shows the T-1000 glancing quickly at an orderly. The orderly is on the floor, clearly injured. How did this man (whom I call, tongue-in-cheek, "a young John de Lancie") get injured?

The below image is from the scene. I can't find an image of the orderly.

[image: Tadfasfsadfeddd]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Sarah beat the snot out of him.](https://vimeo.com/12078669)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You missed the - somewhat relevant - part where (IIRC?) he tried to either sexually or physically abuse her before

Comment: @DVK - Totally different guy.  He got beaten up and locked in Sarah's cell a couple of minutes earlier.  The perv is a fat guy with glasses, and he gets his butt whooped first, then Sarah takes his nightstick and uses it to beat up the thinner, no-glasses guy in my answer. She starts that second attack by throwing the perv's keys at guy #2 to distract him.  Watch the video I linked.

Comment: I completely forgot about that. Mods, feel free to delete this question. Thanks.

Comment: @T-1000'sSon - No reason to delete it.  And for reasons which should be obvious, I'd personally prefer it if you just...  you know... accepted my answer.